# Possible bug in _Document.GetCrossReferenceItems(Object) for MS VSTO Addins?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I want to write a small VSTO addin (in C#) for Word that would place at a selected location in a document a list of cross-references to the document's headings. For this purpose, I thought of using the `GetCrossReferenceItems()` method from the Document class. I have observed, however, a very strange behaviour. If I run the following code:

```
object RefItems = YourDoc.GetCrossReferenceItems(Word.WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeHeading);
```

where `YourDoc` is a reference to the current active document, and then look at the content of the object `RefItems` in the debugger window, I notice that the first ten items are always empty! I've tried this with different documents, and the behaviour is always the same.

[image]

Have you observed this behaviour and would you concur that this is actually a SW bug, or have I maybe missed a configuration that would be needed to successfully use this method?

Comment: How large is the document? There are known issues in very large documents...

Comment: It's not large at all, just a few pages (between 4 and 10).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem on a sample document - just some text with some paragraphs marked in Heading styles. However, I did have to do some *casting* in order to correclty pick up the items, your approach caused errors for me: `Array RefItems = (Array)(object) doc.GetCrossReferenceItems(Word.WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeHeading);`